# how to set serial data type starting point in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

How to set starting point for serial data type in Postgres?

```
ALTER table employee_details ALTER COLUMN emp_id RESTART WITH 1001;
```

Comment: `alter sequence employee_details_emp_id_seq RESTART WITH 1001;`

Comment: it's giving   employee_details_emp_id_seq not exist error

Comment: what is the sequence name for that table?.. `\d+ employee_details ` in `psql`

Comment: my sequence name is : mysequence

Comment: it's showing  [relation "employee_details_emp_id_myserial" does not exist]

Comment: can you psql to the database?..

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)